# cakephp element not displaying

Tags: forms, cakephp, element

I have a number of form inputs inside an element as they are repeated in other forms, however it does not output the content of the element when i include it in a view. I can place "Die();" within the element and it will show everything up until that point including the inputs within the element. When checking the source code (without the "Die();") it seems to have disregarded everything within the element including formatting such as DIV's.

The only thing i can think is that cakephp does not like you setting a form in a view then including inputs to the form using elements, does any one know if this is the case, or know the actual reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is i'm an idiot and forgot to echo the element.... yeah.